# Is the area of a Gaussian proportional to its standard deviation (std)?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Let's suppose that we have a curve that is a Gaussian PDF (probability density function) normalized to an area of one. That is a normal distribution.

If we take that gaussian but change it's std to half of what it was, will this gaussian curve have 50% the space it had, such that we'd need to double the height of the curve to renormalize to a PDF that has an area of 1 again?

If not, how to guess the ratio by which to change the std to apply a reduction of half? In other words, what is the new std for an area multiplier of 0.5, having fixed the mean and the height of the Gaussian.

So, *"Is the area of a Gaussian proportional to its standard deviation (std)?"*

- My guess is that the answer is yes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm guessing you don't want to change the total probability, as that's impossible, but I get the feeling you want to change something indirectly by changing $\sigma$.

Comment: I commented on that on @Greg Martin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution) of the general Gaussian is always to be a probability density function, that is, it is *defined* to always have area 1. Certainly then the value of the density function at $x=0$ will shrink or grow as the standard deviation grows or shrinks.

Comment: I wanted to suppose for a second that the Gaussian wasn't bound to have an area of 1 when re-scaled. I should rather formulate the problem as follow: let's say that the Gaussian is a distribution for a hyperparameter search and that you want to widen this search space by a ratio between 0.0 and 1.0. Will simply creating a new Gaussian with the same mean, but with a `std=old_std*ratio`, do the thing to narrow the space linearly?

Comment: [Ah](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I thought you had a specific problem in mind. Although Gaussian sampling is unbounded, its typical spread is prototypical to $\sigma$ as you've guessed.

Comment: "prototypical to sigma" seems to avoid answering the question with a clear yes or no. I would have prefered a simpler word "proportional". You seem to avoid answering the question, hence why I didn't accept the answer yet. I suggest that you edit the answer to respond something like "no, but yes", where the no is your first answer, and the yes would be the explanation when taking into account my special assumption.

Comment: That comment was made by someone else, not by me. If you have a new question that you'd like an answer to, I recommend asking a new question on this site, or at least editing this question. The more mathematically well-defined the question is, the more likely you are to be satisfied by the answer.